# Line plots in R

Tags: r

I have data as like this

```
data1  data2  data3  data78 data89
10     47     85      52    78
8      78     22            4
4      44     44            5
       77     77            3
              11            7
```

and I need to plot x axis as positions(1-5) and y axis as the counts.. example (I did it on excel)
[image]

I want to do it the same in R .I  tried with line function and it shows error as like this "Error in structure(.Call(C_tukeyline, as.double(xy$x[ok]), as.double(xy$y[ok]),  :
insufficient observations"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ggplot2` you can get the data in long format and plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(id, value, color = name) + geom_line(size = 2)
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(data1 = c(10L, 8L, 4L, 77L, 11L), data2 = c(47L, 
78L, 44L, 77L, NA), data3 = c(85L, 22L, 44L, NA, 7L), data78 = c(52L, 
NA, NA, 3L, NA), data89 = c(78L, 4L, 5L, NA, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `matplot`.

```
matplot(d, type="l")
legend("topright", names(d), col=seq(d), lty=seq(d), horiz=T, cex=.7, bty="n")
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(data1 = c(10L, 8L, 4L, 77L, 11L), data2 = c(47L, 
78L, 44L, 77L, NA), data3 = c(85L, 22L, 44L, NA, 7L), data78 = c(52L, 
NA, NA, 3L, NA), data89 = c(78L, 4L, 5L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```